# the number and the name of the event files in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

```
tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir, sess.graph)
```

1. I found that there are more than one event file in logdir. Why? I think it should be one.
2. what is the meaning of the name, ie:'events.out.tfevents.1496202271.host-name'. What is the meaning of '1496202271' in it.

Thx.

Comment: would you share your program?  it's hard to say from one line why you get multiple  logfiles !

Comment: Not special. Just like official example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different Tensorboard event files are created for separate Tensorflow sessions.

Make sure that you are only running a single session and use it repeatedly when running `saver.save()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is the unix/linux timestamp. For more details refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: thx. But do you know there are more than one event file in logdir?

Comment: yeah，evey file could regard as a checkpoint. See https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables